# Mapping SharePoint to a network directory on a remote machine

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am writing a Java program that would watch all the files in the document libraries of SharePoint 2013 and do something with it. I read online that we can map SharePoint site to a network drive. Since my Java program is running on another machine on the network, I need to be able to access files in the document libraries from a remote machine. I could map SharePoint to a network drive on SharePoint server, but I could not do that on a remote machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realized what was needed to be done. I had to enable Desktop Experience Feature in Windows Server 2012 so that WebClient windows service starts up. Then process of mapping SharePoint to a network drive is the same.

Answer (score 1):

One of the prerequisites of Mapping SharePoint to a network directory on a remote machine is to

- Make sure that The `webclient` windows service has been started.

  - Go to "Run" (windows button + R )> type `service.msc` > make sure that the web client service has been started.

**Note :** If you can't find it try to install Desktop Experience feature as mentioned at [Couldn’t Find WebClient Service Within Services List on Windows Server 2012 R2 / Install Desktop Experience feature](https://blog.devoworx.net/2015/03/24/add-desktop-experience-feature-on-windows-server-2012/)